# Citing academic papers in Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

Wikipedia pages about scientific papers contain many citations. Usually the citations use the "Citation" template, which gives a uniform look to all citations in a page.

I have a large database in CiteULike, and I would like to cite papers from my database in a Wikipedia article I am working on.

Is there a way to automatically convert from CiteULike format, perhaps through BibTeX format, to the format of the Wikipedia Citation template?

I know that there is another template - "Cite doi" - which is much easier to use, but, in some Wikipedia pages it is not allowed to use this template from reasons of uniformity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to export CiteULike citations in BibTeX format, then use [BibTeX2Wiki converter](http://jstools.ucoz.com/bibtex2wiki/) to convert BibTeX citations into Wikipedia's [citation style 1 templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aCitation_Style_1#Templates).